# Count Vowels separately in Java

Tags: java

Example Output:

Enter a string:
hello

A number of each vowel in the string:

```
a: 0
e: 1
i: 0
o: 1
u: 0
other characters: 3
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    int count = 0;
    System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
    Scanner myObject = new Scanner(System.in);
    String anyWord = myObject.nextLine();

    for (int i = 0; i < anyWord.length(); i++) {
      char vowelA = anyWord.charAt(i);
      if (vowelA == 'a' || vowelA == 'A') {
        count++;
      }
    }
    System.out.println("a: " + count);
  }
}
```

This is the code I am writing but I don't know what do to next...
Need your Help...

Comment: You will need different count variables for each vowel.  Perhaps something like `countA`, `countE`, `countI`, etc.  You can then just add more if statements inside your loop to increment these counts.  Also note that in your code, `vowelA` and `vowelB` are the exact same, so there's no reason to keep both variables.  I would just use one variable, and name it something like `character`.

Comment: Do you know about maps? You could have a map with keys that are characters and values that are integers. Each key would be a vowel, and each value would be a count of how many times you've seen that vowel. You could also use a list, like @DerekW's answer does. Or go the way you're going, and just have individual counts...a_count ++, e_count++, etc.  (Sorry for the earlier wording...I had been thinking Python)

Comment: After that first `if` block, use a series of [if...else](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_conditions.asp) statements to determine whether the character was one of the other vowels.  Create separate `count` variables, one for each vowel.  The last `else` block would be for counting all the characters that are not vowels.

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to add my solution here even though other people have working ones. In my opinion, creating a bunch of variables for each unique item you're looking for is bad practice. What if you also want to now accept `y` as a vowel?

Here is my solution, which uses a array of characters to define what characters should be counted. We then create a Hashmap where the key is the character and the value is the count of each character occurrence in the string. We then iterate over the string, incrementing the value of the count in the Hashtable if the key already exists in the Hashtable. Remember, we prepared the Hashtable earlier by doing this. Lastly, we print out all the keys and their associated value.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String []args){
    
        // List of vowels.
        char vowel_characters[] = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};
    
        // Add vowels to dictionary, assign value to zero.
        Hashtable vowels = new Hashtable();
        for (char vowel : vowel_characters) {
            vowels.put(vowel, 0);
        }
    
        // The input string.
        String input = "Hello, world!";
    
        // Check if the character at index `i` is in the dictionary, if so then
        //  add 1 to its counter.
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            char vowel = input.charAt(i);
            if (vowels.containsKey(vowel)) {
                vowels.put(vowel, (int)vowels.get(vowel) + 1);
            }
        }
    
        // Print the results/
        for (Object vowel : vowels.keySet()) {
            System.out.println((char)vowel + ": " + vowels.get(vowel)); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution isn't what was asked for.  The OP wanted help with HIS/HER implementation.   You're not helping the OP learn to code by throwing an complete solution at him/her, especially if it isn't even an extension of the OPs starting work.

Comment: A solution to OPs specific question was already answered. Another solution using his exact implementation is meaningless. You have given him guidance on how to proceed, Derek gave a working implementation using his algorithm, and I gave an implementation using a different algorithm. While OP may choose to continue with his implementation, he can also see how his algorithm could be converted to a different one. Now he has two solutions using two different methods, and can learn from both. If OP does/did not know about Hashtables, now he has a comparison that is significant to himself.

Comment: Both are counterproductive right now.  Later on, come back and provide your full solutions.  Right now, it's best to help the OP to come to a solution without just copying/pasting the whole thing as is from someones answer. - I know this is somewhat controversial, but my goal is to help the OP the best I can....not to win points. - Most Java programs who frequent this space already know how to do this in their sleep.  This question has probably been asked 100 times.

Comment: I whole heatedly disagree. OP has the tools and knowledge to complete his code by looking at what Derek did, and then adding it in himself. If OP decides to copy and paste Derek's solution that is his decision. It is not up to you to decide how OP learns best. OP should ideally be exposed to solutions using different algorithms and then research the different objects and methods they use, and then attempt to implement it on his own, but again that is for OP to decide how he goes about that.

Comment: Does the question ask for a complete solution?  No.  So your answer isn't an answer to THIS question.  Period.